How to Navigate Between Blazor Pages in a .NET MAUI Blazor App When the Destination Page is Not Part of the Shell?
I have a .NET MAUI Blazor app where I'm using a Shell with a TabBar menu. Once I'm on the "HealthSc" page, which is a Blazor page, I want to navigate from the current page to another Blazor page. However, when I try to use the NavigationManager to redirect to a Blazor route, nothing happens. Can someone help me understand how to properly redirect from one Blazor page to another in a MAUI Blazor app, especially when the page is not part of the Shell?
**
MainPage.xaml ---Updated

<TabBar>

        <ContentPage Title="Home" IsVisible="Hidden">
            <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView2" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages1e:Routes}" />
                </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            </BlazorWebView>
        </ContentPage>
   

    <ShellContent Title="Health List" Icon="icons_task.png">
        <ContentPage Title="Health">
            <BlazorWebView x:Name="Survey2" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                    <RootComponent x:Name="root" Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pagese:Home}" />
                </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            </BlazorWebView>
        </ContentPage>
    </ShellContent>

    <ShellContent Title="Add Provider" Icon="account.png">
        <ContentPage Title="Add Provider">
            <BlazorWebView x:Name="Survey1" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                    <RootComponent x:Name="Survey21" Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pagese:Counter}" />
                </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            </BlazorWebView>
        </ContentPage>
    </ShellContent>
</TabBar>

Counter page from this page i want to redirect to a page weather route /weather
**
weather.razor
**
  @page "/weather"
        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <button @onclick="AlertAndNavigate" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
    
    
@code {
    // Inject the NavigationManager
    [Inject] private NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; }

    public async Task AlertAndNavigate()
    {

        Navigation.NavigateTo("/weather");

      //  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Home"); // this is working redirecting to my home shell menu 

     
       
    }
}


I did a test on my side, But I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

https://github.com/MoeezAgha/TabIssueRedrect.git

I pushed the test code to the counter page. When you click on 'IncrementCount,' it should navigate to navigationManager.NavigateTo("/weather"), but it is not working.

After reviewing your code, I found that you didn't put the Routes.razor inside of BlazorWebView  on MainPage.xaml, then the razor pages you want to navigate cannot be identified and routed correctly to.   That's why this problem arises.

@JessieZhang-MSFT I updated the code still same issue

Could you please post your latest code so that we can try on our side?

I commit in https://github.com/MoeezAgha/TabIssueRedrect.git

What I mean by this is that if we want to use NavigationManager for navigation normally on Counter.razor, we should just use <BlazorWebView > wrapper Routes.razor in MainPage.xaml, and no other pages are included.
